# Circular dependency between functions in Common Lisp

Tags: function, lisp, common-lisp

Is it possible to define two functions calling each other in Common LISP without receiving style warning? My best idea to solve that problem is to give one of those functions the second one as an argument, but I don't find that idea to be very elegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Common Lisp defines *compilation units*, and you can even specify manually the scope of a compilation unit using [`WITH-COMPILATION-UNIT`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_w_comp.htm).

For example when you call [`COMPILE-FILE`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cmp_fi.htm), the whole file represents a compilation unit: compilers generally defer warnings at the end of the file, meaning that if you correctly define two mutually recursive functions, there won't be a warning.

Another possibility is to perform a forward declaration:

```
(declaim (ftype function f))
(defun g () (f))
(defun f () (g))
```

The first `declaim` indicates that `f` is to be considered *fbound* (the symbol is bound in the function namespace), suppressing warnings at the point of use during compilation.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course it is, and it does not require any special magic.

Simply define one, and then the other.  If you do this at the REPL or by selectively evaluating individual definitions from a file, or by loading the source of a file, then you may receive a warning as the first function is defined, until the second function has been defined (so you'll only get this the first time you define the first function):

```
cl-user> (defun foo (x)
           (if (null x)
               1
               (bar (rest x))))
; in: defun foo
;     (BAR (REST X))
; 
; caught style-warning:
;   undefined function: common-lisp-user::bar
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     bar
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
foo
cl-user> (defun bar (x)
           (foo x))
bar
cl-user> (foo '(1 2 3))
1
cl-user>
```

In practice you will probably only get warnings like this in compiler-only implementations like SBCL & CMUCL.  There is no reason why other implementations should not warn as well: they typically don't because such warnings tend to be annoying.  They're merely not easy to avoid in compiler-only implementations, assuming you want to see warnings when there really *is* a missing definition.

If you merely put the two functions into a file, and compile them:

```
cl-user> (compile-file "/tmp/x.lisp" :load t)
; Evaluation aborted on #<unknown-keyword-argument {100219F653}>.
cl-user> (load (compile-file "/tmp/x.lisp"))
; compiling file "/tmp/x.lisp" (written 21 APR 2020 04:35:27 PM):
; compiling (defun foo ...)
; compiling (defun bar ...)

; wrote /tmp/x.fasl
; compilation finished in 0:00:00.002
t
cl-user> (foo '(1 2 3 4))
1
```

You won't get any warnings.

In SBCL specifically (and CMUCL probably) you can prevent warnings when loading source files using `with-compilation-unit`:

```
cl-user> (with-compilation-unit ()
           (load "/tmp/x.lisp"))
t
```

This defers warnings from the compiler until the end of the form, at which point all there are none.  I don't think this can be relied on (I think it's harmless in other implementations, but they could still warn).

(Note that each excerpt above is from a fresh SBCL.)

Answer (score 1):

You can define two mutually recursive functions without a style warning in a little convoluted way, given the fact that `defun` is not required to appear at top-level (see [Common Lisp the Language, 2nd Edition](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node66.html#SECTION00931000000000000000)):

> X3J13 voted in March 1989 (DEFINING-MACROS-NON-TOP-LEVEL)   to clarify that, while defining forms normally appear at top level, it is meaningful to place them in non-top-level contexts; `defun` must define the function within the enclosing lexical environment, not within the null lexical environment.

An example is to use the special operator `labels` ([manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_flet_.htm#labels)), that allows the definition of mutually recursive functions:

```
CL-USER> (labels ((f (x)
                    (cond ((> x 0) (g (1- x)))
                          ((= x 0) x)
                          (t (g (1+ x)))))
                  (g (y)
                    (if (= y 0)
                        0
                        (f y))))
           (defun f(x) (funcall #'f x))
           (defun g(x) (funcall #'g x)))
G
CL-USER> (f 3)
0
CL-USER> (g 3)
0
```

Answer (score 0):

That is of course possible. You just have to be careful not to create an infinite loop. So the same applies here as for recursion (you need a termination case).

By the way, SBCL warns when a function calls an undefined function.

pozdrowienia!